# How to define a variable in Lua and how to call it in other Lua script in Cocos2d-x

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

How to define a variable(constant) in Lua and how to call it in other Lua script in Cocos2d-x?

In my way:
main.lua

```
 local r = require("src/Square")
 local constant= r:getConstant()
```

Square.lua

```
function Square:getConstant()
    return 10
end
```

Are there any other more elegant way? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Lua does not know constants (const variables). "How to call (constant)" is unclear, did you mean how to access the variable? Unless the variable is declared 'local' it will be accessible from any script. Same goes for functions. Assuming both Lua scripts run on the same Lua stack.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have edited my post, thanks for your enthusiastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a global variable:

```
constant = r:getConstant()
```

but the variable will not be constant. Lua does not know the concept of immutable/readonly/const variables.

There are tricks to use a Lua table's metatable to prevent the value from changing, though that requires the value to be in the table, and you can't prevent the table from being changed (ie set to nil or its metatable replaced).

Simply using a function that returns a constant value is the easier way to ensure const-ness of the value.

What I've also done in the past is to use a notation that marks constant values, for instance:

```
_constant = 10
local _localConstant = 11
```

The _ prefix denotes the variable as a constant. Alternatively an ALL-CAPS style analogue to #define macros works well if these are known constants in C/C++ or commonly known frameworks (ie DBL_EPSILON or M_PI_2). It is just a reminder for the programmer(s).

Lastly, there's the "const" table which is a global table defining some supposed-to-be constant values:

```
const = {thisIsTen = 10, thatIsEleven = 11}
```

Using the table makes it clear those are constants:

```
result = 100 * const.thisIsTen
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a const(constant) value that's read-only and can not be changed, you'll need to make a function for it (Which you already have). You also have to know that lua gets returns of basic types (number, boolean, nil, string) by value not by reference (Only if you return them by creation).

Here's the replacement for your function:

square.lua

```
Square = {}
Square.__index = Square


local _const = 10

function Square:GetConst()
    local const = _const
    return const
end

-- Test function
function Square:MoveUp()
    _const = _const + 2
end

return Square
```

main.lua

```
local sr = Require("src/Square")

print(sr:GetConst()) -- 10

local plus = sr:GetConst() + 4

print(sr:GetConst(), plus) -- 10     14

sr:MoveUp()

print(sr:GetConst()) -- 12
```

Also take a note that the Square can be changed into a local function(Recommended), so in that case there won't be any troubles with next times creation of object.